# Confusion regarding invertible functions

Tags: functions

The question is elementary but still I want to make sure.
If $f:[a,b] → [c,d]$ is an invertible function then is it right to say that one of these is always true:

$1.  f(a) = c, f(b) = d$

$2. f(a) = d, f(b) = c$

The reasoning is that $f(x)$ must be bijective, hence it must be increasing/decreasing.

Comment: only if $f$ is continuous

Comment: Let $f:[0,3]\to[0,3]$ fix the open interval $(1,2)$ and interchange the closed intervals $[0,1]$ and $[2,3]$ by translation.  Then $f^{-1)(2) =2$.

Comment: @Aadi: When $f$ is continuous, the statement is true; it is a corollary of the intermediate value theorem.